# How can I get visual studio to treat .cl files as source code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, opencl

I'm coding an Opencl project in VS12.

For some reason the VS12 editor does not show me the same source code options in the editor window for the `cl` file as it does for the `cpp` file.

In the `cpp` tab I can see line numbers and when I hoover over a function name it gives me a tooltip etc.
In the `cl` tab I have none of these things.

[image]

I'd really like to have my line numbers and other code features as well.

Is there a way to stop VS from treating .cl files as second class?

**Lying to VS only makes things worse**

If I tell the IDE that a `.cl` file is a C++ file.

`Tools -> Options...`

[image]

`Text Editor -> File Extension`

Add the `cl` extension and set the editor to C++ <kbd>Ad̲d</kbd>

Things get worse

[image]

**How do I get line numbers and other goodies?**

Comment: I like the image of vacuuming function names :D

Comment: _"Is there a way to stop VS from treating .cl files as second class?"_ It's not treating them as second class but it sounds like it doesn't have programming for Intellisense in the OpenCL language.

Comment: At the least it should show me line numbers.....

Comment: Did you look in the _Options_? There are lots of language-specific settings in the "Text Editor" section.

Comment: You could try to enter the file properties in the Project Explorer and try to set the element type to `C/C++`.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, not getting the vacuum reference =(:

Comment: _"when I hoover over a function name"_ :D

Answer (score 3):

You can enable line numbers for plain text via `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `Plain Text` or for all languages @ `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `All Languages`.

The tooltip stuff is Intellisense for C++. I don't think that VS has intellisense support for OpenCL. You can try to set `cl` files to be treated as `C` or `C++` but I don't know how well this will work out in the end.

1. You can *globally* make `cl` files recognized as some desired language @ `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `File Extensions`.
2. You can *locally* make a file recognized as a desired language via its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try code-builder addon of Intel or codexl of Amd. Here is an example from code-builder on visual studio 2015 community edition:

[image]

You don't have to have Intel cpu/cpu. I tried on amd build it worked too.

The plug-in supports the following features:

- New project templates
- New OpenCL code file (*.cl) template
- Syntax highlighting
- Types and functions auto-completion
- Offline compilation and build of OpenCL kernels
- LLVM code view
- Assembly code view
- Program IR generation
- Selection of target OpenCL device - CPU or Intel Graphics